# How can I use GET in codeigniter controller method?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a URL like this 
http://example.com/cronetab/realTimeDeliveryReport?externalId=14133337681891060&deliveredTS=2012-09-10%2013:27:32&status=Deliverd&cause=Successfully%20Deliverd&phoneNo=919995171152

cronetab is the controller name and realTimeDeliveryReport is the method that we invoke.
So we pass parameters in the above format.

How can we take this parameters value in this function?
or 
How can I pass parameter like url?externalId=14133337681891060 this?

Here, The URL is act like a callback URL. So the other server is attaching parameter like this.. So I need solution for this..

Comment: $this->input->get('paramter_name');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the codeigniter manual:

> Enabling Query Strings
>
> In some cases you might prefer to use query strings URLs:
>
> index.php?c=products&m=view&id=345
>
> CodeIgniter optionally supports
>   this capability, which can be enabled in your application/config.php
>   file. If you open your config file you'll see these items:
>
> ```
> $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
> $config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
> $config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
> ```
>
> If you change "enable_query_strings" to TRUE this feature will become active. Your
>   controllers and functions will then be accessible using the "trigger"
>   words you've set to invoke your controllers and methods:
>
> index.php?c=controller&m=method
>
> Please note: If you are using query
>   strings you will have to build your own URLs, rather than utilizing
>   the URL helpers (and other helpers that generate URLs, like some of
>   the form helpers) as these are designed to work with segment based
>   URLs.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Yes.. I have enabled this as TRUE. But when i call this URL, I get the 7 warning like this Message: Missing argument 1 for Cronetab::realTimeDeliveryReport()

Comment: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?';$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO"; I have changed this too

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if is this what you want..

try

```
$_GET['externalid']
$_GET['deliveredTS']
$_GET['status']
```

and so on...

**UPDATE**

try this

function realTimeDeliveryReport() {

if($_GET['externalID'] != "") {

$this->User_model->realTimeDeliveryReport();

}

}

when u use that url the parameters will be saved on $_GET variable and u need to search there, i'm not sure if this will help... but try it ;)

Comment: No.. I mean how to pass parameters like above? In code-igniter the parameters are passing like example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article this. here my_article is the parameter

Comment: You can do that, by submiting a form, to the controller/method URL or using ajax

Comment: Here, The url is act like a callback url. So the other server is attaching parameter like this.. So I need solution for this..

Comment: but, $_GET['externalid'] dont have a value, on realTimeDeliveryReport method after that url is called?

Comment: When I call this url, I get the 7 warning like this Message: Missing argument 1 for Cronetab::realTimeDeliveryReport()

Comment: function realTimeDeliveryReport($externalID, $deliveredTS, $status, $cause, $phoneNo ) {
            if($externalID != "") {
                $this->User_model->realTimeDeliveryReport($externalID, $deliveredTS, $status, $cause, $phoneNo);
            }
            
        }

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Code Igniter Input Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) you should be able to use `$this->input->get('keyName')`

Code Igniter obliterates the GET array, but afaik it still stores it internally so you can access the values using the input library.

The other option is to in your config file set `$config['allow_get_array'] = true;` This will allow you to use the normal method of `$_GET['keyName']`. You may need to set this config value to use the above input library functions as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Please try to pass data in url like below,

http://example.com/cronetab/realTimeDeliveryReport/14133337681891060/2012-09-10%2013:27:32/Deliverd/Successfully%20Deliverd/919995171152

- Then access data in the "realTimeDeliveryReport" controller method like below,

function realTimeDeliveryReport($externalId,$deliveredTS,$status,$cause,$phoneNo){

echo "$externalId,$deliveredTS,$status,$cause,$phoneNo";

}

Answer (score -2):

Try it in view for sending parameters
"/Player/edit_user?id=$row->id?"
Try It in controller
$id = $this->input->get('id');